# pass back data without protcols

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

i need to pass some data to previous view controller, what is problem with my codes? in this code "contactViewController" is my first view controller and "groupViewController" is my second view controller

ContactEditVC.h (firstViewController)

```
#import "GroupEditTVC.h"

@interface ContactEditVC : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    UIImageView * imageView;
    UIButton * choosePhotoBtn;
    UIButton * takePhotoBtn;
    UIButton * btnGroup;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *groupName;
```

ContactEditVC.m (firstViewController)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"selectGroup"]){
        //get selected contact


        //pass selected contact to MyContactAppViewController for editing
        GroupEditTVC *destViewcontroller=segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewcontroller.delegate=self;

    }
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.txtFname.text=groupName;

}

- (void)dataFromController:(NSString *)data
{
   groupName=data;
}
```

And in my second vie controller:

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)dataFromController:(NSString *)data;
@end

@interface GroupEditTVC : UITableViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (retain) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

GroupEditTVC.m (secendViewController)

```
#import "ContactEditVC.h"

@interface GroupEditTVC ()
@end

@synthesize delegate;



- (IBAction)donePressed:(id)sender {  
    [[self delegate]dataFromController:@"blabla"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];    
}
```

**Is there any another way to pass back data?**

Comment: So what's the problem? Does this not work?

Comment: no it's not work,I don't know why?

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. You should add some logs to troubleshoot. In prepareForSegue, log destViewcontroller to make sure you're getting the correct class. In donePressed, log self.delegate to make sure it's not nil. Also, put a log in dataFromController: to see if that method is even called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to follow Model View Controller. In my applications I usually pass around a reference to a Model class that holds a lot of data that I want to share and change. If you pass the model reference to the GroupEditTVC and you change the data in that screen, that changed data is available to the "root" view controller that also has a reference to the same data. The only thing that is needed is that that "root" view refreshes it's views with the new data.

So you don't need to pass anything back, you just update the Model class that the edit view and the main view both have a reference to.

## Example

The idea is to get around passing strings and other "loosely coupled" data around and just act on one solid data object that holds all related data. This is also easier when you start working with AFNetworking / Mantle / etcetera. You just save the whole class of data and you don't have to worry about each little piece of data.

So all references to loose strings should be replaced to strings inside this object.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.txtFname.text = self.contact.name;
}
```

### Data class

```
// class that holds the data
@interface Contact : NSObject // Nothing special, just an object

@property NSInteger contactId;
@property NSString *name;
// You can add basically any data here

@end
```

### Segue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"selectGroup"]){
        //pass selected contact to MyContactAppViewController for editing
        GroupEditTVC *destViewcontroller=segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewcontroller.contact = self.contact; // Adds reference to the same class
    }
}
```

### Done editing

```
- (IBAction)donePressed:(id)sender {  
    self.contact.name = self.name.text; // get new name from text box
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];    
}
```

Comment: Can you supply a tutorial about this topic?